# Which terminal does Vueling use for arrivals in Zurich airport?

Tags: zurich, vueling

I have a friend who freaks a bit with flying and likes to know and plan everything in advance. I tried to help him out but didn't have much success discovering the arriving terminal for Vueling.

The ticket does not mention anything.

Vueling [website mentions terminal 2](http://www.vueling.com/en/we-are-vueling/destinations-and-airports/airports) as their operations terminal but than the ilustration of the aiport, on the same page, shows terminal B (maybe just a name thing).

I tried to double check in the airport website but they have no information about it. I was able to find something in the arrivals table where vueling has a column with nr 1 (maybe terminal?) most of the times and sometimes 2.

**Which terminal does Vueling use by default for arrivals in Zurich airport?**

Comment: Since planes almost always leave from the same gate they've arrived to, it will always be the terminal used by departing Vueling planes. Look up any of their outbound flights on your route and you have your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one terminal.

For departures, there are four gate areas: A, B, D and E (A+B=Schengen, D+E=Non-Schengen), and Vueling usually departs from area A.

For arrivals, there are two areas, namely "Arrivals 1" and "Arrivals 2". Passengers arriving on Vueling usually end up at "Arrivals 1", but your friend's friend will be able to see it on the green arrivals screen

Answer (score 3):

Zurich is effectively a single Terminal although different airside piers are given the names Terminal A, B and E.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrich_Airport):

> **Terminal A** contains gates prefixed A. It opened in 1971, and it is
>   used exclusively by flights to and from destinations inside the
>   Schengen Area, including domestic flights within Switzerland. It takes
>   the form of a finger pier, directly connected at one end to the
>   Airside Centre.

The majority of Vueling flights are served by `A` gates so it is very likely therefore your interest is in Terminal A but some not, so may depend upon whether or not a codeshare and/or the flight's origin.

Comment: Do you know if there are different exits according to the "terminal"? He needs to tell a friend where he is exiting to be picked by car.

Comment: @nsn No, the A, B, D and E designations are **NOT** relevant for arrivals, only departures. There's only "Arrivals 1" or "Arrivals 2" for arriving passengers (see my answer)

Comment: @Crazydre understood. Thank you. It' now clearer.